# How to search in JSON with Javascript fast?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a lemmatization nested dictionaries, like

```
{
{"abbreviate": ["abbreviated","abbreviates","abbreviating"]},
{"abdicate": ["abdicated","abdicates","abdicating"]}
}
```

I want to fast search inside values to get the according key (find `abbreviated` → output `abbreviate`). `Fast` - because the file is about 6MB. This search will be used in a Chrome extension, so i would strongly prefer Javascript, not Python.

What are technics to accomplish such search?

Comment: Use a proper data structure. `l = {'abbr.': ['...']}; console.log(l['abbr.'])` is instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to convert an object to a form for quick hash search:

```
{
    abbreviated: 'abbreviate',
    abbreviates: 'abbreviate',
    abbreviating: 'abbreviate',
    abdicated: 'abdicate',
    abdicates: 'abdicate',
    abdicating: 'abdicate',
};
```

```js
const data = {
    abbreviate: ['abbreviated', 'abbreviates', 'abbreviating'],
    abdicate: ['abdicated', 'abdicates', 'abdicating'],
};

const dictionary = Object.keys(data).reduce((dict, key) => {
    const records = data[key];
    const obj = records.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, [val]: key }), {});

    return { ...dict, ...obj };
}, {});

console.log(dictionary['abbreviated']);
```